# Using int.TryParse with nullable int

Tags: c#

How can I use `int.TryParse` with nullable int?

I am trying to do something like the following, which doesn't compile, obviously.

`int? nr1 = int.TryParse(str1, out nr1) ? nr1 : null;`

What is the correct way to achieve it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because the `out` has to be `int` you need something like:

```
int temp;
int? nr1 = int.TryParse(str1, out temp) ? temp : default(int?);
```

Note that I also use `default(int?)` instead of `null` because the conditional typing won't work otherwise. `? (int?)temp : null` or `? temp : (int?)null` would also solve that.

As of C#7 (VS Studio 2017) you can inline the declaration of `temp`

```
int? nr1 = int.TryParse(str1, out int temp) ? temp : default(int?);
```

Answer (score 5):

`int.tryParse` will change the referenced `out` variable, and return a `boolean`, which is `true` if the passed argument could be parsed as an integer.

You're after something like this :

```
int? int1;
int tempVal;
if (!int.TryParse(str1, out tempVal))
{
    int1 = null;
}
else
{
    int1 = tempVal;
}
```

Comment: This won't compile.

Comment: @Lee realised a second too late that `tryParse` needs an `int`

Comment: "fixed" it. man this looks ugly though